# Is tricky a formal word?

Tags: synonyms, register, formality, formal-language

I am now writing a report which requires me to use formal, academic English...here's the question. I want to describe a task as more difficult, or more challenging than other ones. Can I use the word "tricky"?

If not, is there any other word other than "difficult" and "challenging"?
My first report in English, :) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

*Tricky* is not a formal word.

Some people will say that it is informal. Some people will say that it is ok to use it in informal and formal writing.

*Difficult* and *challenging* are more formal than is *tricky.*

Comment: @XZL - _complicated_ is a good choice; _complex_ might have been another word to consider.